# Using perl to process list of name and details

Tags: regex, file, perl

There are two files. one file is list of names. another file is list of names and details. I want to create 3rd file which contains names from 1st file and details(of that name) from 2nd file. Can you please suggest.

Details from 2nd file are delimited by pattern "list[i]"(which are names from 1st file) and "</reg>"

```
#!/usr/intel/bin/perl


use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;



my $handle;
unless (open $handle, "<:encoding(utf8)", "/nfs/fm/disks/fm_nvm_7138/WLRD_LOGIC_users/cgoudarx/willard_b02/chiplevel/verif/testsuites/upf/pss_ret_regs.txt") {
   print STDERR "Could not open file '/nfs/fm/disks/fm_nvm_7138/WLRD_LOGIC_users/cgoudarx/willard_b02/chiplevel/verif/testsuites/upf/pss_ret_regs.txt': $!\n";
   # we return 'undefined', we could also 'die' or 'croak'
   return undef
}
chomp(my @list = <$handle>);
unless (close $handle) {
   # what does it mean if close yields an error and you are just reading?
   print STDERR "Don't care error while closing '/nfs/fm/disks/fm_nvm_7138/WLRD_LOGIC_users/cgoudarx/willard_b02/chiplevel/verif/testsuites/upf/pss_ret_regs.txt': $!\n";
} 

open ( INPUT, "/nfs/fm/disks/fm_nvm_7138/WLRD_LOGIC_users/cgoudarx/willard_b02/chiplevel/verif/testsuites/upf/tet.xml" ) or die("Could not open xml file.");

my $outffile ="newlist.xml";
open(FILEOUT2, ">$outffile") || die "ERROR: Can't open the output file $outffile: $!";

my $size = @list;

for (my $i=0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    while( my $line = <INPUT> )
    {

        if ( $line =~ m/$list[$i]/) {
            print FILEOUT2 $line;
            while( $line = <INPUT>) # print till empty line
            {
                last if ( $line =~ m/<\/reg>/);
                print FILEOUT2 $line;
            }
            print FILEOUT2 $line;
        };
    };
};

close(INPUT);
```

Comment: Please be more specific. Include examples of the files, and the code you tried

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that the patterns from `tet.xml` are spanning multiple lines, and they are not necessarily in the same order as the keys in `pss_ret_regs.txt`? So you try to pass through `tet.xml` multiple times? That seems like quite an inefficient approach to me.

Answer (score 0):

One of your input files is an XML document. You shouldn't parse XML documents with regular expressions. It is a far better idea to use a proper XML parser (I'd recommend [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML)).

If you insist in parsing XML using regexes, then you cannot process your input file a line at a time, as XML elements will often (usually?) span multiple lines.

Also, please update your file-handling code to use the three-arg version of `open()` and lexical filehandles.

```
open ( my $in_fh, '<', "...") or die("Could not open xml file.");
```

And

```
open( my $out_fh, '>', $outffile) || die "ERROR: Can't open the output file $outffile: $!";
```

Oh, and it's a good idea to standardise on using `or` or `||` in those commands.